# PHP array method for replacing inner array value with different array value having same key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to understand PHP array methods, so Id prefer using the array methods to solve this.

Here is my data:

```
$dataA =>
    array
      0 => 
        array
          'type' => string 'name' (length=4)
          'key' => string 'keywords' (length=8)
          'content' => string 'keywordA' (length=14)

$dataB =>
    array
      1 => 
        array
          'type' => string 'name' (length=4)
          'key' => string 'keywords' (length=8)
          'content' => string 'keywordB' (length=14)
```

What I'd like to do is have the two arrays merged and the final `content` key be:

```
$finalData =>
    array
      0 => 
        array
          'type' => string 'name' (length=4)
          'key' => string 'keywords' (length=8)
          'content' => string 'keywordB' (length=14)
                               ^-- notice here that the content has changed based on the fact that 'key' for both is 'keywords'
```

As you can see, the final content value is from $dataB.

Comment: Does array a or b contain multiple elements with same `key`? do you need numerical indexes to be preserved anywhere?

Comment: take a look now. i voted to close this question, just before because it wasnt correctly worded, so if it does im sorry.

Comment: That edit does not answer any of my question. I provided solution that assumes unique key values and no need for numerical indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Recursive replace does what you want</strike>

```
$finalData = array_replace_recursive($dataA, $dataB);
```

For this particular example, also plus operator will do what you want:

```
$finalData = $dataB + $dataA;
```

But you will have to specify arguments in different order.

There is no such built-in function. You need something to replace only one specific key, only when other is equal it's equivalent in second array, moreover there are associative arrays in zero-indexed ones and you need to compare items only in second-level. If you look at it after describing, you may notice that it is not general functionality that everybody needs, so it is not included in standard function set.

Assuming that `key` value is unique per array, here is solution without visible loops:

```
$getKey = function($item){ return $item['key']; };
$keysA = array_map($getKey, $dataA);
$keysB = array_map($getKey, $dataB);
$finalData = array_values(array_replace_recursive(
    array_combine($keysA, $dataA), 
    array_combine($keysB, $dataB) 
));
```

Comment: i tried array_replace_recursive, and it just combined the two into one array containing two array values

Comment: The indexes arent the same, so its combining them. I need to look for matching key indexes (the actual key called key, which in this example is keywords) and then update the value content since its different

Comment: Sorry but indexes are the same in this example, so I completely don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of `$dataB`, then loop over `$dataA`. If value of `$dataA` is not found in `$dataB`, add it to your copy.